# How do I dynamically load html from memory into an iframe in FireFox with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

In chrome if I have HTML as a string in a var named html I can easily just load it into an iframe and have the iframe execute that html page (with whatever css/jss/etc it might contain) by doing:

```
window.sHTML = html;
iframe.src = javascript:parent.sHTML
```

In Firefox this doesn't work at all.  Is there a way to do this that works in firefox?  Note that I need the JS to execute properly in the iframe.  For example this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9k9Pe/2/ kind of does what I want but if there is a script tag inside the html then that breaks things.

UPDATE:  This actually does work in firefox, it just interacts differently with window.location which was breaking my code.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/avHX8/2/ was that what you wanted?

Comment: I think so, jsfiddle seems to break if I make x = '<script> alert("foo");</script>'  I want to make sure that that would work with the method you're using.

Comment: why not do `$("#i").attr('src', "javascript:alert('foo');");`?

Comment: is this now solved? you should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
window.sHTML = html;
iframe.src = javascript:parent.sHTML
```

This actually does work in firefox, it just interacts differently with window.location which was breaking my code.

To go into more detail, in chrome if you do

```
iframe.src = www.foo.com/bar.html
window.sHTML = html;
iframe.src = javascript:parent.sHTML
```

Then the iframe will execute the html in the html string but its window.location will remain www.foo.com/bar.html and relative links will be treated as though the iframe were from www.foo.com/bar.html

However in FF the window.location becomes javascript:parent.sHTML and relative links will no longer work the way one expects.